# Meaning of "run her way to"

Tags: idiom-meaning

I tried to find the exact idiom in online dictionaries, but could not find any entry on it. Here is the sentence:

"For more than five years, she tried to run her way to a different life."

The text is about a runner who got success after many years of struggle.

Comment: It's not an idiom I've ever heard of... my guess is that the person in question  is an avid runner.

Comment: Without any context to go on, I would read _run_ literally as meaning "use the exercise and discipline of running [in this case, to find her way to a different life]." The only arguable idiom here, in that case, is the idea that "to X one's way to Y" means to attempt to accomplish Y by performing the action X regularly or unstintingly.

Comment: I've also never heard "run [one's] way to [something]" as an idiom. However, a more general form "to [some verb here] [one's] way to [something]" is commonplace, and means to habitually or persistently perform an action until it brings about an end result. In this case, then "run her way to a different life" could mean performing running as an exercise until it brought about a new (and presumably improved) phase of life.

Comment: @SvenYargs, The text is about a runner who got success after many years of struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "She was trying to make a different life for herself, and the means she used to try to achieve that purpose was running." It's highly figurative and not a common use of English.

If she had been a musician, the person might have written *"she was trying to play her way to a different life"*, and if she had been a programmer, *"she was trying to program her way to a different life"* and so on.